# How to add basic preemptive authorization with SSL keystore for apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, ssl, basic-authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x, keystore

Following is the code that I am currently using to set HttpClient. But for some webservice endpoints I also need to add Basic preemptive authorization with username and password. I tried to implement the code found here or similar to this one: http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication. But it was not successful, because none of the examples I found included SSL Keystore part. Could anybody help me to enhance this code? Thanks in advance!

```
public static HttpClient getHttpsClient(final String strWSEndPoint) throws Exception {

    HttpClient client = null;
    if (strWSEndPoint.contains("https://")) {

        final SSLContext sslcontext = getSSLContext();

        final SSLConnectionSocketFactory factory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1.2" }, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(factory).setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER).build();
        return client;
    } else {
        client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        return client;
    }

}

private static SSLContext getSSLContext() throws Exception {
    final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());      
    final FileInputStream instreamkey = new FileInputStream(new File("whatever.jks"));      
    try {
        keyStore.load(instreamkey, "password".toCharArray());
    } finally {
        instreamkey.close();
    }
    final org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder objSSLContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());
    if (true) {
        final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        final FileInputStream instreamtrust = new FileInputStream(new File("whatever.jks"));            
        try {
            trustStore.load(instreamtrust, "whatever".toCharArray());
        } finally {
            instreamtrust.close();
        }
        objSSLContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(trustStore);
    }
    return objSSLContextBuilder.useTLS().build();
}
```

If it will help, attaching an image of how it would look like in SOAP UI. [image: here is the soap ui example]

Comment: You mentioned attempting to implement basic auth but your code example doesn't seem to have any mention of it. Could you include a copy of your attempt?

Comment: @Staros The user doesn't know at all how to add Basic authentication in this code made for SSL, so, no attempt. Maybe adding Basic auth header would be sufficient ? I re-tagged the question to give focus.

Comment: No, Basic auth header will not be enough